# Persist docker container log before it gets destroyed

Tags: docker

We have an automatic deploy system so whenever someone pushes something on the main branch, a new docker container is created and the old one destroyed.

Naturally, all logs are no longer accessible for the old container at that time.

Is it possible to do something like, before the old container is destroyed, copy all the logs to a location, destroy the container and start up a new one?

Comment: it is possible for you to bind a directory using volumes on your machine ie /path/to/logs to a path that you write logs to inside your docker container. So when the image writes a log, it actually writes to /path/to/logs

Comment: You can run `docker logs` after you `docker stop` the old container but before you `docker rm` it.  What do the actual mechanics of the update sequence look like?  What you describe definitely seems possible; how are you managing the logs now?  (Is this a programming question or more of a system-administration question?)

Answer (score 2):

As json and text container logs are stored in the container path, they do have the very desirable property that when the container is cleaned up, so are they.

So, your options are:

1. Don't clean up the containers until you no longer need the logs
2. Use a tool like promtail to forward the logs to elasticsearch or loki for later examination in Grafana
3. Use one of dockers built in log drivers to forward logs to a persistent log sink: one of `awslogs`, `fluentd`, `gcplogs`, `gelf`, `journald`, `logentries`, `splunk`, `syslog` (This list can be extended via docker log plugins)